# Passing on data-frame to generate HTML table - Python

Tags: python, html, pandas

I would like to generate an HTML table, but do not understand how I can pass on the data frame. Suppose df is the data frame based on which an html table is going to be generated, I want to pass the content of the data frame (all the td components) to the class function. However, I only get the header (th) of the table. I don't really care about the html style at this point, but the table cells based on "df".

Here is my code:

```
class htmltable():
    def __init__(self, _data, _cols, **kwargs):
        self.data = _data
        self.cols = _cols

        self.html = """\
            <table>
        """

        for col in self.cols:
            self.html += """\
            <th style="%(thstyle)sfont-size: 11px>%(thlabel)s</th>
            """ % {
                'thlabel': col['label'],
                'thstyle': col['style'] if 'style' in col else ''
                }

        self.data_dict = self.data.to_dict().values()

        super(table, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_html(self):
        self.html += """</table>"""
        return self.html


df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['John', 25, 'good'], ['Bob', 22, 'super'], ['Chris', 33, 'nice']]),
               columns=['Name', 'ID', 'Comment'])
html = df.to_html(index=false)

rpt_cols = [{'label': 'Name', 'style': 'width: 60px;'},
        {'label': 'ID'},
        {'label': 'Comment'},
        ]

rpt = table(df, rpt_cols)

print(rpt.get_html())
```

Basically, I want to pass on a data dictionary into an HTML table, using a class. The reason to use "Class" instead of "df.to_html" is because I need to generate various reports based on this single data frame (df). For some reports, certain columns are not needed; or in other cases I would like to have some highlights. Now the main issue is how to get the actual cell contents.

Comment: Can you add the expected HTML output?

Comment: This is far too broad/vague. Stack Overflow is for **specific technical issues**, not guides, tutorials or documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can take my below code for reference:
you can do styling with `style.format` and use render.

```
def html_input(c):
    return '<input name="{}" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="100" value="{{}}" />'.format(c)

def html_button(c):
    return '<input name="{}" type="submit" value="{{}}" />'.format(c)

dict_style = {}
func = [html_input, html_button]
for idx, c in enumerate(['id', 'age']):
    dict_style[c] = func[idx](c)
x = df.style.format(dict_style)
print(x.render())
```

Comment: in place of c pass the `rpt` and customize the function as per your need.